# Transition matrix & Expectation

Tags: probability, expectation, average, transition-matrix

I have a problem that need to calculate the average.

> 10 cities are arranged in a line. 2 cities are connected to two
>   bridges, one is a good bridge, one a bad bridge. Passing the bad
>   bridge will collapse and back again. So what is the average of
>   number of good bridges which we need to pass to go through from $1^{st}$ city to
>   $10^{th}$ city.

I see that transition matrix to bridge changing has style

\begin{pmatrix}
 \frac{1}{2}& \frac{1}{2}  &0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
 \frac{1}{2}& 0  &\frac{1}{2}  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
 \frac{1}{2}  &0  & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
 \frac{1}{2}  &0  & 0 & 0& \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
 \frac{1}{2}  &0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
 \frac{1}{2}  &0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
 \frac{1}{2}  &0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 &0 \\ 
 \frac{1}{2}  &0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2}  &0 \\ 
 \frac{1}{2}  &0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  &0 & \frac{1}{2}\\ 
 0 & 0  &0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &1  
\end{pmatrix}

But I don't know how to calculate the average of number of good bridges to move from $1^{st}$ country to $10^{th}$ country.

Please help me solve this problem.

Thank in advance

Comment: Looking at how you've set up the problem, if you go on the bad bridge, you go to the first city?  The wording in the problem is confusing, and I'm not sure that it implies your interpretation.  If a bridge collapses, is it still there to take later? (if not, this is not a markov chain).  Was it translated from another language?  Regardless, I suggest tackling the problem by induction: solve the city for $n$ cities, then use that to solve for $n+1$.

Comment: I think we have to get back from the first city if we go through bad bridge. Unless, we alway go to 9 good bridges to come from 1 to 10 city

Comment: If the bridge collapses when you try to use it and you have to start over, all the good bridges will be used at least once, but I think the question probably wants you to count driving over the same bridge twice as counting or two good bridges that need to be crossed.  I will accept your interpretation (that you start over from the beginning) since otherwise the problem is uninteresting.  Since you cannot drive over a bridge that is already collapsed, this will NOT be a markov chain.  The question that remains: if you have driven over a good bridge before, do you remember that it is good?

Answer (score 1):

Let us interpret the problem as follows: If a bridge collapses while you are on it, then you start over from the first city.  If you succeed in taking a bridge once, you take that bridge every other time you can.

How many good bridges do you have to drive over?  We note that we can determine our path at the end of the trip just by seeing which bridges have collapsed.  For example, if the only bridge to collapse was between 3 and 4, then we drove to 3 (giving 2 good bridge crossings), started over, then drove to 10 (giving 9).  More generally, if the bridge from $i$ to $i+1$ collapsed, it will add an additional $(i-1)$ good bridge crossings to our list.

Because each bad bridge has a $1/2$ chance of collapsing during the trip, the expected number of good bridge crossings is $9+(1/2)(0+1+\ldots+8)=9+\frac{8*9}{4}=27$.

More formally, let $B_i$ be the event that you drive on the bad bridge leaving city $i$ the first time you try to leave city $i$, and let $X_i$ be the random variable that is $(i-1)$ if $B_i$ happens, and $0$ otherwise.  Then the number of good bridge crossings is given by the random variable $9+\sum X_i$, and by linearity of expectation, 
$$E(9+\sum X_i)=9+\sum E(X_i)=9+\sum E((i-1) 1_{B_i}),$$
where $1_{B_i}$ is the indicator function for the event $B_i$.  This is then equal to
$$9+\sum (i-1)E(1_{B_i})=9+\sum (i-1)P(B_i).$$

However, each particular bad bridge has a $1/2$ chance of being driven over, because it will only be driven over the first time you visit the corresponding city, and your choice of the good or bad bridge is equally likely at this point.

Comment: Could you explain more about your final solution. The probability you cross over both bad & good is 1. And if you only pass for 1 good, probability is 1/2. So how you get that result?

Comment: You will pass over every good bridge at least once, but if you drove over every good bridge the first time, you would never drive over any bad bridges.  The first time you come to a city, you have a 1/2 chance of driving over the bad bridge to the next city.  Every other time you come to that city, you will always take the good bridge out.